# Why do method overloads break Azure Function routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

Let's say I have a C# method in an Azure Function project that looks like this, and works perfectly:

```
[FunctionName( nameof( GetContents) )]
public static async Task<IActionResult> GetContents( [HttpTrigger( AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route="/v1/Contents/{id}" )] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, string id ) {
// ...
}
```

So far so good. Now, create an overload that has no route at all, is not a web service at all, and is only intended to be used as a helper for other services:

```
public static async Task<ObjectResult> GetContents( ILogger log, string id, bool isAdmin ) {
// ...
}
```

Now, the original web service method no longer routes properly. You get a 404 if you try to hit it. This, despite it already working perfectly and nothing changing about it. How does the overload manage to destroy the functionality of the original method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Function host attempts to resolve the method using a cascading approach, starting with an explicitly defined method named as the `entryPoint` inside the compiled `function.json`. See [FunctionEntryPointResolver.cs#L39](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/69111926ee920d4ba10829c8fa34303bb8165a42/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/DotNet/FunctionEntryPointResolver.cs#L39)

If the entry point method name could return more than 1 public method, the Azure Function resolver will throw an exception due to ambiguity. See [FunctionEntryPointResolver#L94](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/69111926ee920d4ba10829c8fa34303bb8165a42/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/DotNet/FunctionEntryPointResolver.cs#L94)

```
private static T GetNamedMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> methods, string methodName, StringComparison stringComparison) where T : IMethodReference
{
    var namedMethods = methods
                .Where(m => m.IsPublic && string.Compare(m.Name, methodName, stringComparison) == 0)
                .ToList();

    // If we have single method that matches the provided name, use it.
    if (namedMethods.Count == 1)
    {
        return namedMethods[0];
    }

    // If we have multiple public methods matching the provided name, throw a compilation exception
    if (namedMethods.Count > 1)
    {
        throw CreateCompilationException(DotNetConstants.AmbiguousFunctionEntryPointsCompilationCode,
            $"Ambiguous function entry points. Multiple methods named '{methodName}'.", $"Multiple methods named '{methodName}'. Consider renaming methods.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very surprised that this is the implementation because it basically forces the function name to be globally unique, which has never been the case before in C#. But, it is indeed the implementation.

Comment: I agree. I would suspect a better approach is discovery of the entry point using the decorator above the executing method.